# What's required of a web server in order to offer up streaming (but not live) video?

Tags: server, bandwidth, video

What's required of a web server in order to offer up streaming video?  Where would you start?

Edit: Let's assume it is **not** real-time or live streaming, just canned videos.

Comment: I'd suggest making your question more specific, possibly including a link to an example of what you'd like to do.

Comment: Streaming as in real-time video chat streaming or just viewing static video files hosted on the server?

Answer (score 3):

A combination of [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) and the open source [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) flash application do a great job of streaming archived video from a website.  The City of Nanaimo is using these tools along with [Adobe's Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/) and [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for their council video archives ([example](http://www.nanaimo.ca/CouncilMeetings/VideoArchive.aspx?clip=C100621V))

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/wowza/

Comment: For more information on Flowplayer's pseudostreaming -- as well as links to server technologies that support it:

http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html

Answer (score 1):

For IIS you can install the [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/media) addin.

Here is a tutorial on streaming with Apache: [Video Streaming With Apache](http://blog.lebrijo.com/?p=161&language=en)

Answer (score 1):

IIS 7 offers Smooth Streaming which is Microsoft’s implementation of HTTP-based **adaptive streaming**. For more details, check this [Smooth Streaming FAQ](http://alexzambelli.com/blog/smooth-streaming-faq/) & a [step-by-step implementation guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndSettingUpAndEncodingForIIS7SmoothStreamingAndSilverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why so many people are pointing you to streaming servers, what you are looking to achieve certainly does not require a streaming server deploy.

You can achieve what you'd like to do with most webservers.

Heck - IIS 6.0 can do this if you add the MIME types :)

nginx - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFlvStreamModule
apache - http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2006/07/11/mod_flvx/